# OpenGL automatically "smooths" sprites in games like DOOM, Duke Nukem 3D, etcetera on System76 laptop with Intel graphics -- make it stop!

Tags: graphics, games, intel-graphics, opengl

this is my first-ever time posting on StackExchange, so please be gentle with me.

I am an aficionado of retro first-person shooters like DOOM, Duke Nukem 3D, etcetera. As you may recall, enemies/objects in these games are two-dimensional sprites. A lot of modern source ports use OpenGL to render graphics, which is great, however:

On my brand-new (purchased October 2016) System76 laptop with Intel graphics, OpenGL is automatically SMOOTHING the two-dimensional enemy/object sprites, even in programs where there is the option to turn off this feature. I want retro, blocky sprites! I'm pretty sure there must be a hack I can apply to fix this, but I've done a lot of Google searches and haven't found any information on how I can change it.

Running Ubuntu 16.10, though I've also run 16.04 and even Fedora 24 on this laptop and I'm still getting the same issue. Can anyone help?